# Can unicode characters which are not part of font family be rendered from fallback font family set?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, font-family

I'm using font family Monserrat to render Unicode subscript characters. These are computed values from Chrome Dev tools inspector:

[image]

Body of this element is

```
CH₂O₂ - example 2
```

and result looks like this:

[image]

Subscript characters are looking different then `2` in the end of this example.

**Is there a possibility that subscript characters were taken from some other `fallback` font? And if `YES`, how to check which font family was applied to them?**

Comment: do you check your normalize codes for different style??